# Does there exist a real valued function representing the distance?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space and let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow X$ be a continuous function.

Then, does there exist a function $g:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $d(f(x),f(y))=|g(x)-g(y)|$ for all $x,y\in [a,b]$?

If not, what if $f$ is absolutely continuous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, no.

Example: Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be defined by $f(x) = e^{2\pi i x}$. If $g:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfied $|g(x)-g(y)| = |f(x)-f(y)|$ for all $x$ and $y$, then
$$\left|g\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-g(0)\right| = |e^{\frac{\pi i}{2}} - e^0| = |i-1| = \sqrt{2} \\
\left|g\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) - g\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\right| = |e^{\pi i}-e^{\frac{\pi i}{2}}| = |-1-i| = \sqrt{2}.$$
This means that $g\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-g(0)$ is either $\sqrt{2}$ or $-\sqrt{2}$, and similarly $g\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) - g\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)$ is $\pm\sqrt{2}$, so $g\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) - g(0) = g\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) - g\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)+g\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-g(0)$ can be $-2\sqrt{2}$, $0$, or $2\sqrt{2}$. But
$$\left|g\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) - g(0)\right| = |e^{\pi i}-e^0| = |-1-1| = 2,$$
contradiction.